# How to wrap text in textview in Android

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

Does any one know how to wrap text in TextView in Android platform. i.e if the text in textview exceed the screen length it should be displayed in the second line.

I have searched and tried the following:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false",
android:inputType="textMultiLine",
android:singleLine="false"
```

But none work..

Can anyone suggest how can I do it.

Comment: TextViews should word-wrap by default.  Can you post your whole layout?

Comment: By any chance is the Textview inside a table layout? If so I have an answer for you.

Comment: In my case, after adding about half a dozen attributes (described below) to force the textview to wrap text over multiple lines, without success, I noticed I had an attribute **`android:inputType="textPersonName"`**. Apparently it had been added by the Android Studio design tool. Removing that attribute fixed the problem! There may be other input types that prevent wrapping too.

Answer (score 78):

## Constraint Layout

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/some_textview"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textview_above"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_to_right"/>
```

- Ensure your layout width is zero
- left / right constraints are defined
- layout height of wrap_content allows expansion up/down.
- Set `android:maxLines="2"` to prevent vertical expansion (2 is just an e.g.)
- Ellipses are prob. a good idea with max lines `android:ellipsize="end"`

---

0dp width allows left/right constraints to determine how wide your widget is.

Setting left/right constraints sets the actual width of your widget, within which your text will wrap.

[Constraint Layout docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

Comment: Yes! This is exactly how it works!
Just make sure you set the width to 0dp

Comment: setting the left & right constraints helped make it wrap for me, instead of the text overflowing beyond the right bounds

Comment: This is not working within a linearlayout, if there is another control on the sides, it will push them out of the screen.

Answer (score 65):

For me this issue only occurred on Android < 4.0

The combination of parameters I used were:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

The maxLines count seemed to be the random final piece that made my TextView wrap.

Comment: I know its an old thread now but thought I would post my findings. I used only the 'android:maxLines' and then it wrapped my text. Cheer @Guykun

Comment: Again, this is tantamount to simply setting the height of the TextView to `match_parent`, which is not the same thing as making the TextView's height expand to include the extra lines.

Answer (score 36):

For the case where the `TextView` is inside a `TableLayout`, the solution is to set `android:shrinkColumns="1"` on the `TableLayout`. (Replace `1` with the column number the TextView you want to wrap is in. (0-indexed))

AFAICT, no other attributes are needed on the `TextView`.

For other cases, see the other answers here.

FWIW, I had initially gotten it to sort of work with

```
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/inventory_text"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:width="0dp"
```

but that resulted in some extra empty space at the bottom of the Dialog it was all in.

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Otherwise my words are cut off

Comment: `stretchColumns` on the table is also working for me, and actually giving me better results

Answer (score 21):

> Use `app:breakStrategy="simple"` in `AppCompatTextView`, it will control over paragraph layout.

It has three constant values

- balanced
- high_quality
- simple

> Designing in your TextView xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textquestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Your Question Display Hear....Your Question Display Hear....Your Question Display Hear....Your Question Display Hear...."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:breakStrategy="simple" />
```

> If your current minimum api level is 23 or more then in Coding

```
yourtextview.setBreakStrategy(Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE);
```

For more refrence refer this [BreakStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy)

[image: Textview breakStrategy image]

Answer (score 13):

You must use 2 parameters :

- `android:ellipsize="none"` : the text is not cut on textview width
- `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` the text wraps on as many lines as necessary

Comment: That's not working for me. (FWIW, I have a TextView in a TableRow in a TableLayout.)

Answer (score 8):

This should fix your problem: `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: This just causes the TextView to expand to take as much space as possible, which is the same as setting the Height to `match_parent`.  Not quite the same thing as OP wanted.

Comment: In the case of TableLayout, `layout_weight="1"` fixed the problem for me. However, my TableRow that contains the TextView, had `layout_height` set to a specific value. Maybe will be useful for someone

Answer (score 5):

OK guys the truth is somewhere in the middle cause you have to see the issue from the parent's view and child's. The solution below works ONLY when spinner mode = `dialog` regardless of Android version (no problem there.. tested it in VD and DesireS with Android =>2.2) :

1. .**Set you spinner's(the parent) mode like :**

   ```
   android:spinnerMode="dialog"
   ```
2. **Set the textview's(child custom view) properties to :**

   ```
   android:layout_weight="1"  
   android:ellipsize="none"  
   android:maxLines="100"  
   android:scrollHorizontally="false"
   ```

I hope this works for you also.

Comment: Tried so many things to make it work in 'dropdown' mode but nothing worked. Now settled down on 'dialog' mode.

Answer (score 5):

By setting `android:maxEms` to a given value together with `android:layout_weight="1"` will cause the TextView to wrap once it reaches the given length of the ems.

Comment: Works for TextView placed in RelativeLayout too.

Comment: have been searching for hours, thanks it works great on constraintLayout too

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio 2.2.3 under the `inputType` property there is a property called `textMultiLine`. Selecting this option sorted out a similar problem for me. I hope that helps.

Comment: This is for EditText, not Textview

Answer (score 2):

Try @Guykun's approach

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

Also, make sure that parents width is not set to wrap content. This is the thing that I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Just was working on a TextView inside a layout inside a RecyclerView.  I had text getting cut off, ex, for `Read this message`, I saw: `Read this`.  I tried setting `android:maxLines="2"` on the TextView, but nothing changed. However, `android:lines="2"` resulted in `Read this` on first line and `message` on the 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Following change made it work -

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

The ellipsis, maxLines, or layout_weight - all didn't make any difference.
Note - The parent width is also set as wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to set your *textview width*.

**android:layout_width="60dp"**

you can change the width to your choice.  Just type long sentence to check if it working like this

**android:text="i want to be among world class software engineer"**

Answer (score 0):

Strange enough - I created my TextView in Code and it wrapped - despite me not setting anything except standard stuff - but see for yourself:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
childParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

Label label = new Label(this);
label.setText("This is a testing label This is a testing label This is a testing label This is a testing labelThis is a testing label This is a testing label");
label.setLayoutParams(childParams);
```

As you can see from the params definition I am using a LinearLayout. The class Label simply extends TextView - not doing anything there except setting the font size and the font color.

When running it in the emulator (API Level 9) it automatically wraps the text across 3 lines.

Comment: Note the use of this code `LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`. Most likely that does the wrapping you consider to be "automagic"

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android 2.2 and my textview will automatically goto the next line if it exceeds the screen.

If you would like to have the text goto the next line before the end of the screen, just add in (just put in your own dp value). This will be useful if you have a picture on the right of the text.

```
android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `layout_with` to a definate size, when the text fills the maximum width it will overflow to the next line causing a wrap effect.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/segmentText"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/segmentHeader"
    android:text="You have the option to record in one go or segments(if you swap options 
    you will loose your current recordings)"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is with the textView width, try to make it dedicated number like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I've tried many solutions without any result, I've tried:

```
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

the only one thing triggred the wrap option is the dedicated width

Comment: are you doing this within a Linerlayout because it still extends to next line for me within a LinearLayout with android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your TextView in a ScrollView with something like this :

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/SCROLL_VIEW"  
android:layout_height="150px"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent">  

<TextView   
   android:id="@+id/TEXT_VIEW"   
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
   android:text="This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header" />  
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply But my aim is to wrap the text when it exceed the line length not to put a horizontal scroller.