# Textview that doesn't show full text

Tags: java, android, xml, tableview

I'm creating a simple layout with a TableLayout and TableRow, that contain two TextViews. This is a part of code.

```
<TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:stretchColumns="0">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/myTableRow">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Short description"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Large description"/>

    </TableRow>
```

The problem is that if there is long text in TextView1 then full text is not showing. How can I show full text in TextView1?

Comment: do you want the text to appear multi-line and wrap?

Comment: If the text is very long, yes, I want to display multiple lines

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851659/how-to-wrap-text-in-textview-in-android

Comment: Not to sound rude, but you should google for an answer first. There are plently of solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out the update XML what have you given in question...may be this is what you wanted to do.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/myTableRow" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Short description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Large description" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

to display multiple lines add :

`android:ellipsize="none"`  //the text is not cut on textview width:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false"   //the text wraps on as many lines as necessary:
```