# text is not fully displayed in textview

Tags: android, string, textview

Textview ["text_body_story"] is not fully displaying the content. I have used the following xml code.   I have used a listview, then when one of the items is selected, it displays my assigned string from string array. My string is extremely large sometimes upto 4000 words.  The following xml code is inside of a relative layout.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_story_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="text_story_name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_author_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_author_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#000000"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeSplitBackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_body_story"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_body_story"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

**How can I display the whole text in the textView?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textview that doesn't show full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834285/textview-that-doesnt-show-full-text)

Comment: I have seen it and tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

To display multiple lines add :

```
android:ellipsize="none" //the text is not cut on textview width

android:scrollHorizontally="false"   //the text wraps on as many lines as necessary
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have already tried it. Is there any other suggestion that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to use:

```
<TextView
        android:singleLine="false"
/>
```

or

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

with

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: Wow.. to strange.