# How to wrap the TextView : Android

Tags: android, textview

[image: Two separate textviews]

> My question is both are two separate textviews "Hello" and  "World" First textview has character limit of 32. How can I make it wrap content if text exceeds the limit and make "World" stay in first line?
>
> Below is the image thats how its acting currently.

[image]

> Below is the code which I tried to implement. I tried to write **min_ems**, **max_ems** and **ems** but its not looking good in tablet.

```
<ImageView
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/img_profile"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    android:src="@drawable/active_profile"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView_profile_name"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_profile_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_light"
    android:text="Hello"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img_profile"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView_profile_device_count"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:maxEms="12" **//this code can be a typo I added in stackoverflow**
    android:minEms="2"    **//this code can be a typo I added in stackoverflow**
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_profile_device_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp30"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView_profile_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img_arrow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_light"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img_profile"
    android:text="(3 Devices)" />

<ImageView
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView_profile_device_count"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
/>
```

Comment: Check this SO will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851659/how-to-wrap-text-in-textview-in-android

Comment: @Manjuboyz  It kind of solved the issue, the only thing is if you write small text in first textview, then its leaving space between two textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:maxLength="32"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I added that later, but my issue is `maxLength = 32` wont fit all 32 in same line in a particular screen. It should be dynamic based on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want second text show only in first line you can do this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_profile_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_light"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Hello"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_profile"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView_profile_device_count"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_profile_device_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp30"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img_arrow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_light"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img_profile"
    android:text="(3 Devices)" />
```

With this, you second text will always stay in first line. And first text length will set to 0dp it means that first text length will start from `end of img_profile` to `start of textView_profile_device_count`

But it may still have some problem if text of first textview wider than width of textview, and it will not fully show.

PS. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: its not working out. if you `maxLines = 1` to 2nd textview it will just get disappear if user enters more characters in 1st textview. And also dont think ems is good when it comes we have to manage for tablet and phone both. I tried it and tested on tablet it doesnt looks good