# TextView email suffix ".com" breaks into new line (fixing without breakStrategy)

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I have a problem with proper display of an email in `TextView` and have completely no idea but I feel like there is a simple flag for that.

Having example email: **aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com**

it should break on the screen based on the length but for some reason it breaks **.com** into new line. I dont want **.com** to break into new line.

Current min Api is 21, so `android:breakStrategy` cannot be applied.

Without .com:

```xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmailcom" />
```

[image]

With .com:

```xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com" />
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51772744/4168607

Comment: There is an answer under that duplicate as linked by @ADM, you need to use AppCompatTextView and app:breakStrategy="simple". The whole purpose of various AppCompat extensions is to GIVE you access to new features in lower API levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by just setting [android:breakStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setBreakStrategy(int)) to `simple`.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:breakStrategy="simple" <!-- Add this line -->
        tools:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com" />
```